# getting Thunderbird rescan imap folder

Tags: linux, imap, thunderbird

Since I got an external program (imapfilter) modifying my imap folder, thunderbird keeps loosing track of new messages. Messages are moved upon arrival in sub-folders, making Thunderbird unable keep tracking them - therefore I have no clue which folders to look for new messages, and newly created folders (even I subscribe them after creation) does not show up until I restart the mail client.

Is there any extension or setting for Thunderbird  which I could use to trigger re-scanning my folder tree?

Please don't waste time on advices like

restarting Thunderbird: takes a great amount of time, or

"use Evolution (or any other mail client)", or

use internal mail filters: they are not sophisticated enough or

procmail/fetchmail: I'm arranging a remote imap server for good

EXTENSION 1:

even folders can be created in the background, without Thunderbird would know it has been created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a very similar problem when I started using server-side filters to deliver mail directly into folders rather than into my inbox.

The solution I found was to tell Thunderbird to explicitly check each folder for mail. To do this right-click on the folder, go to "properties", then under the "General Information" tab check the bottom checkbox labled "Check this folder for new messages".

This is slightly laborious in that you have to do it to each folder, but you only have to do it once.

Hope that helps,

Bart.

Comment: as the folders are created "in the background", without Thunderbird knowing it, I wouldn't see the folder itself... so changing folder props are not applicable. But a good answer, I admit. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

what about `mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new`?
*(question-marked because i've just ran into this and will start testing this switch now)*

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Checking_for_new_messages_in_other_folders_-_Thunderbird#IMAP

this whole check many-imap-folders thing **could** still be a bit iffy no matter how you do it, as this ancient https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=221792 is still kept in a state of NEW.